# How to access the project root folder

Tags: python, eclipse

Below is a screenshot of my project. While I can access my `_files_inner` folder quite easily with `pd.read_csv("./_files_inner/games.csv")` I find it tricky to access my 'root' folder `_files`

if you see my project explorer, I'm trying to access the `_files` but without specifying the absolute path (i.e., `C:\\Users\\adhg\\dev\\py\\_files\\games.csv`) because other developer have different path.

Question: how to access the root `_files` folder with something like this one (doesn't work)`pd.read_csv("./_files/games.csv")`:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_result = pd.read_csv("./_files/games.csv")  #will not work
csv_result = pd.read_csv("./_files_inner/games.csv") #works 

print csv_result
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added `__init__.py` in files folder?

Comment: No. But say I do that, what should be the relative path?

Comment: try using `../_files_inner/games.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try using ../_files_inner/games.csv`